# Pip package working locally but not if i install it via pipenv into another environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I created a pypi package for an api to get the lessons from my school and uploaded it to pypi but when I install it, it doesn't get recognized. It works just fine locally when.

I have tried deleting some lines from the startup.py like `modules: []` but it doesn't seem to change anything and still works locally just fine

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
  long_description = fh.read()

setup(
  name="zermelo.py",
  version="1.0.0",
  license="MIT",
  url="https://github.com/wouter173/zermelo.py",

  description="Zermelo api wrapper library for python.",
  long_description=long_description,
  long_description_content_type="text/markdown",

  package_dir={"zermelo": "zermelo"},
  install_requires=["requests>=2.17.0"],

  classifiers=[
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
  ]
)
```

Below is my file hierarchy:
[image]

The source code is put into a `__init__` file like this:

```py
from .client import Client
```

and in the `.client` file which is `client.py` I have a class called `Client` with some functions but I don't think this has anything to do with it as it works just fine locally

I try to import the package into a project like this:

```py
from zermelo import Client
```

Which works locally but not in a pipenv.

These are the commands I use to upload the package to pypi:

```sh
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

and this is how I use my pipenv:

```py
pipenv --python 3.7
pipenv install zermelo.py
pipenv shell
python
>>> from zermelo import Client
```

But again that does not work and I have no idea why.

When I import it in pipenv:

```py
from zermelo import Client
```

It gives returns an Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zermelo'
```

I have tried putting different names and capitalizing zermelo but nothing works to import Client from zermelo but locally

```py
from zermelo import Client
```

works the way I want to it returns the Client from the **init**.py file.

Comment: Could you tell what is not working? Do you get an error? If yes, please provide the stacktrace. If not, please explain what you expect and what you actually obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setup.py` lists nothing to install. You must use `packages=<a list of packages>` or `py_modules=<a list of .py modules>`.

See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/